# How to make filter function that doesn't stop at first false?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to filter an array of objects by comparing it to another array by looping through it's values.
The problem is that the filter function stops at the first false by default, so if the loop returns (false, true, false) it will not pass the filter.

is there a way around this?

code (I've put simplfied arrays and objects in the code for the example):

```
const jobs = [
    {id: 1,
    location: 'AA'},
    {id: 2,
    location: 'BB'},
    {id: 3,
    location: 'CC'},
]
const filteredLocations = ['AA', 'CC']
const filteredJobs = jobs.filter(function(el, i) {
    do {
        return el.location === filteredLocations[i];
    }
    while (filteredLocations.length >= i)
})
// this only returns the first object instead of the desired first and third
```

Thank you!

Comment: see [Array#includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) `return filteredLocations.includes(el.location)`

Comment: That's what `return` does. It return's a value from the function (the one you are passing to the `.filter()` function) and terminates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.filter` function as it is intended, any return will be added to the returned array.

```
const jobs = [
    {id: 1,
    location: 'AA'},
    {id: 2,
    location: 'BB'},
    {id: 3,
    location: 'CC'},
]
const filteredLocations = ['AA', 'CC']
const filteredJobs = jobs.filter(el => {
    return filteredLocations.includes(el.location);
});
```

sidenote, your code has 2 issues:

1. it may return false inside the while loop, if it doesnt match the 1st occurrence, hence why the single output you had
2. you compare `filteredLocations.length` with the `i` (index) of the `jobs` array loop, `jobs` and `filteredLocations` are 2 different arrays, so that doesnt make sense to do so

Answer (score 0):

Filter doesn't stop at first false. It works correctly but it cannot return the first and third objects because the third object is on index 2 and you don't have any items in `filteredLocations` on that index.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to replace the `do`-`while` loop with a simple finder function as follows:

```js
const jobs = [
    {id: 1,
    location: 'AA'},
    {id: 2,
    location: 'BB'},
    {id: 3,
    location: 'CC'},
]
const filteredLocations = ['AA', 'CC']
const filteredJobs = jobs.filter(function(el, i) {
    return filteredLocations.find((filteredLocation) => filteredLocation === el.location);
})
console.log(filteredJobs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let filtered = jobs.map(j => filteredLocations.every(fl => fl == j.location));
```

Comment: Can you please add some more details? What does this code do? Where should it be placed? How does this fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

*How to make filter function that doesn't stop at first false ?*

`filter()` never stop at first false. It will check for all the true values which passed the applied condition and return those elements from the array in a new array.

To achieve the requirement, You can simply use the single line of code in the filter function instead of `do-while` loop.

Demo **:**

```js
const jobs = [
    {id: 1,
    location: 'AA'},
    {id: 2,
    location: 'BB'},
    {id: 3,
    location: 'CC'},
];

const filteredLocations = ['AA', 'CC'];

const filteredJobs = jobs.filter(({ location }) => filteredLocations.includes(location));

console.log(filteredJobs);
```